# Finding full page height

Tags: javascript, scroll, height

I used window.scrollYMax in firefox to get the max scroll, and used window.scrollY to find how close I was to the bottom of the page so that I could load more feeds. Problem is window.scrollYMax doesn't work outside of firefox! Help!

Comment: are you trying to get the height of the document? any code?

Comment: Are you not using JQuery YUI etc libraries? If you are not you should considering one they have really handy function for all these things

Comment: I don't use JQuery, and yes Kieran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are Firefox-specific. This page gives a good explanation of what browsers support what: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html.

You might be looking for:

```
x.scrollWidth
x.scrollHeight
```

Comment: Doesn't work because the body element doesn't stretch the whole page.

Comment: The body doesn't stretch because of my floats.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but shouldn't body already be set to overflow: auto by default?

Comment: I'm not sure, but some browsers might not set it by default. In either case, that property fixes a *lot* of glitches, ==.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need `document.body.scrollHeight`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works great for me -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <embed id="pdf" src="your-source-of-pdf" width="100%" height="" type='application/pdf'>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
          $(function () {
             $('#pdf').attr('height', document.body.scrollHeight);
          });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```