# jQuery/JavaScript calculate scroll height

Tags: javascript, scroll, height

What is the best method/function to calculate scroll body height of window? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding full page height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813523/finding-full-page-height)

Comment: and an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044230/difference-between-screen-availheight-and-window-height

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).height();
```

That should do it (reference: http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: Not this. I need the scroll body height, not scroll top or document height.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```